# Delete local file after uploading to S3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file

I've below php coding to put an object to S3 bucket.
When I try to delete the local file after uploading it gives me the error '*file busy*'.
Even I `unset` the variable the problem doesn't solve.

```
                try {
                    $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
                    $resultS3 = $s3->putObject(array(
                        'Bucket'     => $aBuket,
                        'Key'        => $aS3Path,
                        'SourceFile' => $iconFileUrl,
                    ));
                } catch (S3Exception $e) {
                    $e->getMessage();
                }

                unset($s3);;    //release the s3 variable
                $result = Storage::disk('admin')->delete($iconFile);
```

`$result` is `false` always.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. you can use `\Storage::disk('s3')` directly https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#s3-driver-configuration

Comment: what is $iconFile value?

Comment: @muhammad-dyas-yaskur $iconFile is only the filename. There's nothing wrong with this command `Storage::disk('admin')->delete($iconFile);` Because if I add this line before S3 upload, it deletes the file successfully.

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thanks for your reply, but is there any other workaround I could apply?

Comment: laravel provides great solution and that used by thousand people  what else workaround  you need ? and it is offical  documented

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes, I can use `Storage::disk('s3')`  but without using packages blindly I wanna know what's going on here. Would like to learn something new.